# Getting started with Dropbox SDK

Tags: ruby, dropbox-api

I'm looking at the Dropbox SDK for the Ruby platform http://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ruby, trying to figure out how to use APIs

from my  Users/myname directory on my Mac, I did `gem install dropbox-sdk`

It's supposed to come with some example files to play around with

> web_file_browser.rb is an example web app that lets you browse and upload files to Dropbox.

It also says

> For ease of compatibility, these examples reference a local copy of the library you installed with RubyGems, located in lib/dropbox_sdk.rb.

1) What folder do I have to be to test these sample files?

2) After I get my app key, how do I run a sample file to test uploading?

3) should I in theory have been able to run this sample file from a Rails application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solutions:**

**1)** What folder do I have to be to test these sample files?
***Soln:*** You have to be in the directory where these files are located.e.g On my machine, it is

```
jatin@silverSpoon:/media/silverSpoon/dropbox-app/dropbox-ruby-sdk-1.1$ ls
CHANGELOG  cli_example.rb  dropbox_controller.rb  gemspec.rb  lib  LICENSE  README  web_file_browser.rb
```

So, you have to be in `dropbox-ruby-sdk-1.1`folder to test these sample files.

**2)** After I get my app key, how do I run a sample file to test uploading?
***Soln:*** Go through this [Ruby Setup with Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ruby) again. It's written that:

> To get these examples running, you'll need to edit each script(.rb file) to
>   enter your app key and app secret where indicated. Also make sure that
>   the access type is set to :app_folder or :dropbox as configured for
>   your app. After this, simply run **ruby script.rb** and you are done.

**3)** should I in theory have been able to run this sample file from a Rails application?
***Soln:*** Yes, why not. I'd advise you to play around with the sample Sinatra app, get used to the API and then move onto Rails.

Comment: thanks, i will test this when I get home tonight and get back to you with an upvote if it works