# Rails: Storing .pdf files in dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, download, dropbox

I am using the paperclip, dropbox, and paperclipdropbox gems in an effort to upload and download old exams (.pdfs) from a single dropbox account to avoid paying for Amazon S3 services. I am able to upload files to the account without a problem using the following controller method:

```
def upload_exam
  if params[:document]
    @exam = Exam.new(:course_id => params[:course], :user_id => current_user.id, 
    :professor => params[:professor], :term => params[:term], 
    :document => params[:document], :description => params[:description])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @exam.save
    format.html { redirect_to test_bank_path, notice: 'Exam was successfully uploaded.' }
  else
    format.html { render action: "upload_exam" }
  end
end
```

In an effort to download the file I am using the same send_file method that works to send paperclip files from the public directory of my application in the download_exam controller:

```
send_file @exam.document.path, :filename => @exam.document_file_name,
:type => @exam.document_content_type, :disposition => "attachment"
```

But this runs the error

```
Cannot read file /documents/documents/18/original/ASCE_7-05_Chapter_3.pdf
```

I believe my application is looking in the public folder for the file and my research hasn't found a way of downloading from the dropbox folder. If anyone has experience with this, please help!!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8517327/643500